# Select multiple checkbox dropdown not working (html/ js)

Tags: javascript, html

I am running the below code in my system but the dropdown box is not working. I ran in JSFiddle, its working fine but in my system, its not. I tried in Chrome, Firefox and Safari as well but no luck.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
<html>
<body>
<select name="cars" id="cars" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="santro">Santro</option>
</select>
<script>
  $("#cars").multiselect({
    buttonText: function(options, select) {
    console.log(select[0].length);
    if (options.length === 0) {
        return 'Add To';
    }
    else {
      var cars_selected = [];
      console.log(options);
      options.each(function() {
          cars_selected.push($(this).val());
      });
      return cars_selected.join(', ') + '';
    }
   }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting this in my browser:

[image: I am getting this in my browser]

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ejqngpn5/893/

Comment: works fine for me.

Comment: yes it works in jsfiddle, but not working in my system, is it related to Mac somehow, I cant figure out any other way to make it run

Comment: Are you using the same jQuery in your system as you are in the Fiddle? https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js is ancient.  Replace it with: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: yes, in my file its 3.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working locally on my Mac by adding `jQuery` 1.9.1 and `bootstrap-multiselect.js`. Check to make sure these are being included in your local.

Comment: I have these, do I need any other?
bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js, ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js, bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css, bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js

Comment: No that should be fine. Are you getting any JS errors in your consol?

Comment: oh yeah, followed the errors and at the end I was getting this error: "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3", i changed the jquery.min.js to 1.11.3, thanks so much